# Why does the Home app not let me set my temperate exactly when in auto?

Tags: temperature, homekit

I have an ecobee 3 and I can't set the temperature exactly when using the home app while in Auto mode, instead it jumps to the degree directly above or below the desired temperature. When in Cold mode I can set the temperate in one degree increments. When using the ecobee app I can set the temperate in one degree increments in any mode. I assume this is a bug. Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Did you try asking the maker of the device/app?

Comment: Apple is the maker of Home.app...